# SSH tunneling on Ubuntu (Private IP of one network to Private IP of another network)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh-tunnel, private-ip

Suppose I use a Ubuntu machine in a computer lab which has a private IP like 10.255.1.34. At my home I use Internet provided by a local ISP, so my home PC has a private IP like 172.16.203.105. I am just user in both places. Is it possible to connect these to PCs by SSH tunneling??
You can also suggest me any alternative ways.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You want to have two private IP's communicating over the internet? Unless you can forward the ports on both sides (to be able to ssh from A to B and vice versa, otherwise you will only be able to connect one way): no.

Alternatives? You can setup a VPN server somewhere with a public IP or a an IP/port that get's forwarded.

Answer (score 0):

The following may not be real ssh tunneling but an alternative solution to your issue. First of all..

- On your home network firewall/router you have to setup a forwarding rule. Say you have port 2022 forwarded to 22 on  172.16.203.105. Which means you can ssh to your home-pc "172.16.203.105" like shown below.

  ssh -p 2022 "YOUR-PUBLIC-HOME-IP"

The next step is ssh tunnel , you can do this per-application or for the entire PC

- For the entire just do

  ```
    ssh -X -p 2002 "YOUR-PUBLIC-HOME-IP"
  ```
- Just want access port 80 on your PC

  ```
     ssh -L 2112:72.16.203.105:80 "YOUR-PUBLIC-HOME-IP"

     Note:-  Port 2112 is a random port you can choose any unused port >1000
  ```
- Say you want to mount your home file system on your local workstation

  ```
     sshfs -p 2022 user@YOUR-PUBLIC-HOME-IP  /local-mountpoint
  ```

Home this answers your question.